# Terminal emulator s3270 - Roll Up action as400

Tags: python, ibm-midrange

I am automating with python a p3270 terminal and I am using a s3270 emulator for this. I can automate all the screens but in one I have to use the Page Down key.

I am using this library https://github.com/mstiri/p3270/tree/master/p3270 and I have tried with this

```
terminal.s3270.do("NEXT")
terminal.s3270.do("PF(8)")
terminal.s3270.do("PA(2)")
terminal.s3270.do("Pg Dn")
```

None of these options work for me, or maybe I'm missing some step, what is the action I should send for the page down key?

In this wiki I didn't find anything :/ https://x3270.miraheze.org/wiki/S3270/Actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page Up and Page Down in 3270 are usually mapped to F7 and F8. But then I see you already incorporated this in your commands file.

You maybe want to study the Chapter about 3270 support on OS/400 in this document, [SC41-5420-03](https://ibmdocs.pocnet.net/SC41-5420-03.pdf), PDF Page 192 (*Step 10—3270—Setting the Default Keyboard Mapping*). OS/400 is a 5250 platform, and 3270 support might be somewhat different to that of MVS.

Comment: Yes, in the library I was using, the F8 sent it like this PA(1) PF(8) but I noticed that only PF(8) works.